# How can I listen for more than one key using keyboard library?

Tags: python

I want my python code to listen to specific keys and do something when they are pressed.
This is what I tried:

```
while True:
   if keyboard.is_pressed('f4'):
      print("f4 is pressed!")
   elif keyboard.is_pressed('f5'):
      print("f5 is pressed!")
```

It kind of works but because of the infinity checks the program slows my pc and I need something more efficient.

Then I tried this:

```
while True:
   keyboard.wait('f4')
   print("f4 is pressed!")
```

It works much smoother but now I don't know how to make the `wait()` method to listen to 2 keys or more in the same time.
Should I try some multithreading? I'm not sure what is my best option and how to do it.

Comment: Per the example given on the [`keyboard` github page](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#example) you could register hotkey callbacks for the keys you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you it works perfect!

Comment: you can also add time.sleep(0.1) in your while loop. it may fix the first code